# Pointers to stack

Tags: pointers, memory, stack

I am sorry that I cannot support my question with some code (I didnt understand how to structure it so it would be accepted here), but I try anyway.

If I understand correctly, a struct that references a struct of same type would need to do this with contained pointer for reference. Can this pointer reference to allocated space on the stack (instead of the heap) without creating segmentation fault? -

how should this be declared?

Comment: There's nothing special you have to do when you declare. Whether a pointer is going to point to stack, heap, or NULL has no effect on how a structure containing it is declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use pointers to variables on the stack, but only when the method that provides that stack frame has not returned.  For example this will work:

```
typedef struct
{
    int a;
    float b;
} s;

void printStruct(const s *s)
{
    printf("a=%d, b=%f\n", s->a, s->b);
}

void test()
{
    s s;
    s.a = 12;
    s.b = 34.5f;
    printStruct(&s);
}
```

This will cause an error however, as the stack frame would have disappeared:

```
s *bad()
{
    s s;
    s.a = 12;
    s.b = 34.5f;
    return &s;
}
```

**EDIT**: Well I say it will cause an error, but while calling that code with:

```
int main()
{
    test();
    s *s = bad();
    printStruct(s);
    return 0;
}
```

I get a warning during compilation:

```
s.c:27:5: warning: function returns address of local variable [enabled by default]
```

and the program appears to work fine:

```
$ ./s
a=12, b=34.500000
a=12, b=34.500000
```

But it is, in fact, broken.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I believe I get why it should be broken - but why does it still work?

Comment: It's most likely because the stack hasn't be *reused* since the function returned and so everything that was there before is still valid.  If other functions (with stack variables) was called in between then it would certainly fail.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what language you are working in, so assuming C for now from the wording of your question... the following code is perfectly valid:

```
typedef struct str_t_tag {
   int foo;
   int bar;
   struct str_t_tag *pNext;
} str_t;

str_t str1;
str_t str2;
str1.pNext = &str2;
```

In this example both str1 and str2 are on the stack, but this would also work if either or both were on the heap. The only thing you need to be careful of is that stack variables will be zapped when they go out of scope, so if you had dynamically allocated str1 and passed it back out of a function, you would not want str1->pNext to point to something that was on the stack within that function.

In other words, DON'T DO THIS:

```
typedef struct str_t_tag {
   int foo;
   int bar;
   struct str_t_tag *pNext;
} str_t;

str_t *func(void)
{
    str_t *pStr1 = malloc(sizeof(*pStr1));
    str_t str2;
    pStr1->pNext = &str2;

    return pStr1; /* NO!! pStr1->pNext will point to invalid memory after this */
}
```

Comment: would `sizeof(*pStr1)` work if `pStr1` is not initialized (as is the case when processing the `malloc` line)?

Comment: yes - sizeof is evaulated at compile time and there's no need to initialise the contents to know how big they will be.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is specifically a C/C++ question, but I'll give C/C++ code as example in anyway.

The only way you can declare it: (with minor variations)

```
typedef struct abc
{
  struct abc *other;
} abc;
```

`other` can point to an object on the stack as follows:

```
abc a, b; // stack objects
b.other = &a;
```

This is not a question about scope, so I'll skip commenting on possible issues with doing the above.

If, however, you want to assign it to a dynamically created object, there's no way this object can be on the stack.

```
abc b;
b.other = malloc(sizeof(abc)); // on the heap
```

Comment: great and elaborate answer:)

Comment: @dexter, if this or any other answer helped you, then please upvote it (using the up arrow to the left of the answer) and / or accept it (using the green tick, also to the left of the answer).